# error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<String>

Tags: java

I am getting the below error.

```
Line 15: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<String>
```

integer.toString() returns a `String` instance and I am adding that to a list of Strings.
Why does it give boolean cannot be converted to error. Because return value is `String` and value I want to add is also a `String`.

```java
class Solution {
    public List<String> findMissingRanges(int[] nums, int lower, int upper) {
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (nums.length == 0) {
            if (upper - lower == 2) {
                // String a=Integer.toString(lower+1);
                // res.add(a);
                res.add(Integer.toString(123));
            } else if (upper - lower > 2) {

                return res.add(Integer.toString(lower) + ">" + Integer.toString(upper));
            }
        }

        int r = upper;
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

            if (i == 0 && nums[i] - lower >= 2 && res.size() == 0) {
                upper = nums[i];
                flag = true;
            } else if (i != nums.length - 1) {
                upper = nums[i + 1];
                lower = nums[i];
            }
            if (i == nums.length - 1) {
                lower = nums[i];
                upper = r;
            }
            if (upper - lower == 2) {
                // int temp=lower+1;
                Integer temp = new Integer(lower + 1);
                res.add(temp.toString());
                if (i == 0 && flag == true) {
                    i--;
                    flag = false;
                }
            } else if (upper - lower > 2) {
                int a = lower + 1;
                if (i == 0 && flag == true) {
                    i--;
                    a = lower;
                    flag = false;
                }
                int b = (i == nums.length - 1) ? upper : upper - 1;
                String subRes = a + "->" + b;
                res.add(subRes);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is "line 15" that is causing this error?

Answer (score 6):

You are doing `return res.add(...);`, and the `add` method returns a boolean value (in fact, I just checked out of curiosity, and it seems to always return `true`).

If you want to return the List, just do:

```
res.add(...);
return res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method type returns `List` but when you call `res.add` you're not returning the list - instead, you're returning the value 'true' because that's what adding to a list returns, as per the docs. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)

Answer (score 0):

[`List.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) returns a boolean value.

> returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call

Since, you are returning `res.add()`, it is returning `boolean` from the function. But, Your function definition says defines the return type to be `List<String>`. Hence, the error.

You should return the list at the end of the function.

```
public List<String> findMissingRanges(int[] nums, int lower, int upper) 
{
    List<String> res=new ArrayList<String>();
    //Do operations on res
    return res;
}
```